# Unable to download files from Google Cloud Storage: ValueError("%r could not be converted to unicode" % (value,))

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to download a file from my Cloud Storage bucket using Python:

```
GCP_BUCKET_NAME = "my-learning-bucket"
storage_bucket = storage_client.bucket(GCP_BUCKET_NAME)


def download_object(download_obj_name):
    blob = storage_bucket.blob(download_obj_name)
    blob.download_to_file_name(f"downloads/data.db")
```

But it gives me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/asnimansari/Desktop/tradestation/ares/main.py", line 22, in <module>
    root.run_click_commands()
  File "/Users/asnimansari/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1137, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/asnimansari/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1062, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/asnimansari/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1668, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Users/asnimansari/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Users/asnimansari/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 763, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/asnimansari/Desktop/tradestation/ares/commands/import_data.py", line 9, in import_data
    import_latest_data_from_gc()
  File "/Users/asnimansari/Desktop/tradestation/ares/helpers/import_data_from_gc.py", line 8, in import_latest_data_from_gc
    db_names_in_gcp = get_db_names_in_gcp()
  File "/Users/asnimansari/Desktop/tradestation/ares/helpers/gcp.py", line 29, in get_db_names_in_gcp
    donwload_object(bobu)
  File "/Users/asnimansari/Desktop/tradestation/ares/helpers/gcp.py", line 13, in donwload_object
    blob = storage_bucket.blob(download_obj_name)
  File "/Users/asnimansari/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/bucket.py", line 688, in blob
    return Blob(
  File "/Users/asnimansari/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 205, in __init__
    name = _bytes_to_unicode(name)
  File "/Users/asnimansari/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/_helpers.py", line 389, in _bytes_to_unicode
    raise ValueError("%r could not be converted to unicode" % (value,))
ValueError: <Blob: tradeenginedata, quotes/quotes_2021-06-10.db, 1623310593606516> could not be converted to unicode
```

The file is a sqlite database.

Comment: Can you check the file encoding on Google CLoud console? Are you able to download the file with gsutil?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere `gsutils` works, I am able to download using it.
file encoding is `application/octet-stream`

Comment: Can you share your dependencies?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere  `google-cloud-storage==1.38.0`. I also do the file upload from the same codebase.

Comment: Do you use Flask? It's maybe a dead end, but with Cloud Function you need to use (if you need to define it) a special version of Flask else you have conflict with click dependency version. I don't know if it could be a too recent version of click which have a bug and then cause this issue...

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I am not using flask. This a  standalone python code, which I am running behind a virtual environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you've already opened a [GitHub Issue link](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/issues/463) and there's already a response from the Cloud Storage Team.

As they mentioned, the error comes from the fact that you're passing an invalid String to [`storage_bucket.blob()`](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/buckets.html#google.cloud.storage.bucket.Bucket.blob). As additional insight, we can see from the error that a Blob Object is actually being passed in, rather than String.

Therefore, please make sure that `download_obj_name` is a valid String and not a Blob Object.

Also, you must correct your typo in the download method and notice the extra underscore. The correct method is `download_to_filename()`, not `download_to_file_name()`.